How to wrap text in LaTeX tables with multirow
I have some problem with my table.. it's overflow of the page. Here is my code. I have tried to set width but I guess it because of multirow, text is not wrapped

\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular} {|p{0.35\linewidth}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|} 
\hline 
  Models &  \textbf{Candidate Retrieval} &  \textbf{MedMentions} & \textbf{BC5CDR} \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Triplet Loss + All samples} & SR & 70.7 & 85.8 \\
& DR & 70.3 & 87.8 \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Triplet Loss + Down-sampling} & SR & \underline{71.6} & 86.1 \\
& DR & 71.3 & 88.1 \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Prototype-based Triplet Loss} & SR &  71.5 & 86.2 \\
& DR & 71.4 & \underline{88.2} \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Prototype-based Triplet Loss + SRN} & SR & \textbf{71.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} & 87.0 \\
& DR & 71.7 & \textbf{88.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Acc@1 produced by four settings on the development set of MedMentions and BC5CDR. Emboldened numbers indicate the best performing system, while underlined ones indicate the second best. ``SR" stands for sparse representation. ``DR" stands for dense representation. \textcolor{blue}{(*) indicates statistical significance compared to the others (with $p$-value $<$ 0.05)}}
\label{tab:dev_results}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document} 


Please comment out more packages: you'll only need a fraction of them to compile your example AND may impose a heavy update burden, e.g. for novices, just to try your code. Thank you

@MS-SPO hi just edited

Hint: Find said documentclass here: https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes

\mutirow is doing nothing useful here. (You might need it in the title row instead.)  Anyway, you can't use {*} with a p column.  You have to use the width.  Note that \linewidth is not a constant.

I've taken the liberty of adding (a) the instruction \usepackage{xcolor,caption} in order to make the code compilable and (b) a screenshot. Feel free to revert.

I would switch to a tabularx environment and allocate less space to the three data columns. I would also do away with all vertical rules and employ fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules. I'd do away with the \multirow wrappers as they are preventing automatic line-breaking. I'd use a non-extended bold font for the emboldened numbers and align them on the decimal markers, and I'd load the ulem package and use its \uline macro instead of \underline.
There's no need to embolden some of the header cells. Finally, I'd shorten the text that goes into the argument of \caption and make the remaining material a legend rather than part of the table's caption. Aside: I don't understand why the asterisks are rendered in blue.

\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
%\usepackage{multicol} %% not needed
\usepackage{tabularx} 
%\usepackage{multirow} %% not needed
%% new:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\nbold}[1]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1} % Non-extended Bold

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\captionsetup{justification=centering, 
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Xccc @{}} 
\toprule 
Models & \mytab{Candidate\\Retrieval} & \mytab{Med-\\Mentions} & BC5CDR \\
\midrule
Triplet Loss + All samples & SR & 70.7 & 85.8 \\
& DR & 70.3 & 87.8 \\
\addlinespace
Triplet Loss + Down-sampling & SR & \uline{71.6} & 86.1 \\
& DR & 71.3 & 88.1 \\
\addlinespace
Prototype-based triplet loss & SR &  71.5 & 86.2 \\
& DR & 71.4 & \uline{88.2} \\
\addlinespace
Prototype-based triplet loss + SRN & SR & {\nbold 71.9}\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{*}} & 87.0 \\
& DR & 71.7 & {\nbold 88.9}\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{*}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Acc@1 produced by four settings on the development set of MedMentions and BC5CDR.}
\label{tab:dev_results}

\smallskip\small
Emboldened numbers indicate the best performing system, while underlined ones indicate the second best. ``SR'' stands for sparse representation, and ``DR'' stands for dense representation. \textcolor{blue}{*}~indicates statistical significance compared to the others, with $p$-value${}< 0.05$.

\end{table}

\end{document}


Aside: Omitting all vertical lines and interior horizontal lines also makes it much easier  for readers to see which cells have underlined numbers.

Ja my original code didn't have those line, I was trying to fix the problem LOL. Thank youuuuu

the asterisks are rendered in blue  just for review purpose, I'll delete it later. Thank youuuuuu

But like, I want to make it center in the cell. But it's okay to be like that.

Hey, Sorry, I just have time to check this, and have tried this code on Overleaf. And it didn't work.  can you check this again?

@jupyter - The } character somehow got deleted in the preamble line \usepackage{caption}. Fixed now. Sorry 'bout that.

Since I went to the effort of fixing the code...
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}% remove

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{tabular} {|p{\tempwidth}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|} 
\hline 
  Models &  \textbf{Candidate Retrieval} &  \textbf{Med-Mentions} & \textbf{BC5CDR} \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{\tempwidth}{Triplet Loss + All samples} & SR & 70.7 & 85.8 \\
& DR & 70.3 & 87.8 \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{\tempwidth}{Triplet Loss + Down-sampling} & SR & \underline{71.6} & 86.1 \\
& DR & 71.3 & 88.1 \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{\tempwidth}{Prototype-based Triplet Loss} & SR &  71.5 & 86.2 \\
& DR & 71.4 & \underline{88.2} \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{\tempwidth}{Prototype-based Triplet Loss + SRN} & SR & \textbf{71.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} & 87.0 \\
& DR & 71.7 & \textbf{88.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Acc@1 produced by four settings on the development set of MedMentions and BC5CDR. Emboldened numbers indicate the best performing system, while underlined ones indicate the second best. ``SR" stands for sparse representation. ``DR" stands for dense representation. \textcolor{blue}{(*) indicates statistical significance compared to the others (with $p$-value $<$ 0.05)}}
\label{tab:dev_results}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document} 


Hi John, the center environment should be replaced by \centering.

Plus numerous other changes.  I quit when I got it to work.

Thank you @John

@JohnKormylo I imagined it :D

With tabularray, two examples: without or with booktabs:
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l]*3{Q[l,3cm]}},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    cell{1}{2-Z}={font=\bfseries}
    }  
    Models & Candidate Retrieval & Med\-Mentions & BC5CDR \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Triplet Loss + All samples & SR & 70.7 & 85.8 \\
    & DR & 70.3 & 87.8 \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Triplet Loss + Down-sampling & SR & \underline{71.6} & 86.1 \\
    & DR & 71.3 & 88.1 \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Prototype-based Triplet Loss & SR &  71.5 & 86.2 \\
    & DR & 71.4 & \underline{88.2} \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Prototype-based Triplet Loss + SRN & SR & \textbf{71.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} & 87.0 \\
    & DR & 71.7 & \textbf{88.9\textcolor{blue}{*}} \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Acc@1 produced by four settings on the development set of MedMentions and BC5CDR. Emboldened numbers indicate the best performing system, while underlined ones indicate the second best. ``SR" stands for sparse representation. ``DR" stands for dense representation. \textcolor{blue}{(*) indicates statistical significance compared to the others (with $p$-value $<$ 0.05)}}
\label{tab:dev_results}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l]*3{Q[c,3cm]}},
    cell{1}{2-Z}={font=\bfseries}
    }  
    \toprule
    Models & Candidate Retrieval & Med\-Mentions & BC5CDR \\
    \midrule
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Triplet Loss + All samples & SR & 70.7 & 85.8 \\
    & DR & 70.3 & 87.8 \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Triplet Loss + Down-sampling & SR & \underline{71.6} & 86.1 \\
    & DR & 71.3 & 88.1 \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Prototype-based Triplet Loss & SR &  71.5 & 86.2 \\
    & DR & 71.4 & \underline{88.2} \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Prototype-based Triplet Loss + SRN & SR & \textbf{71.9\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{*}}} & 87.0 \\
    & DR & 71.7 & \textbf{88.9\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{*}}} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Acc@1 produced by four settings on the development set of MedMentions and BC5CDR. Emboldened numbers indicate the best performing system, while underlined ones indicate the second best. ``SR" stands for sparse representation. ``DR" stands for dense representation. \textcolor{blue}{(*) indicates statistical significance compared to the others (with $p$-value $<$ 0.05)}}
\label{tab:dev_resultsb}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you @Car;

@jupyter You're welcome!
